# dalekjs, calling loops inside module.exports test

Tags: npm, phantomjs, dalekjs

Hi I just want to ask if there is a way that you can call loops inside module.exports?

```
module.exports = {
'GZAIS Create New Asset': function (test) {
  test

  .assert.exists('input#asset_name', 'asset input exists')
  .assert.exists('textarea#asset_description', 'asset description exists')
  .assert.exists('input#asset_type', 'asset type exists')
  .assert.exists('input#date_purchased', 'date purchased exists')
  .assert.exists('.filter-option', 'status exists')
  .assert.exists('input#serial_number', 'Serial Number exists')
  .assert.exists('input#supplier', 'Supplier field exists')
  .assert.exists('input#reason', 'Reason for purchase field exists')
  .done();
}
};
```

right now this is my design on asserting the fields if fields are existing, what I want to do is use a for loop to avoid so much repetition.

so it would pretty much look like this

```
var assetInput = ['asset_name','asset_description','asset_type','date_purchased','serial_number','supplier','reason'];
module.exports = {
'GZAIS Create New Asset': function (test) {
  test
    for(var i=0; i<assetInput.length; i++){
      .assert.exists('input#'+assetInput[i], assetInput[i] + 'exists')
    }
  .done();
}
};
```

but the problem is this code won't work, do you guys have any idea how can I implement loops inside module.exports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, this is just a simple syntax error.
You are missing a `test` in front of

`.assert.exists('input#'+assetInput[i], assetInput[i] + 'exists')`

this must be turned into:

`test.assert.exists('input#'+assetInput[i], assetInput[i] + 'exists')`

Comment: This worked out well for me. Thanks, is dalekjs also able to call outside functions of module.exports?

Comment: Sure. You can require everything you want and execute it. Everything is just "normal" node.js/javascript code :)